# 8.1u1 RDP "The logon attempt failed"

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am unable to connect to a new install of windows 8.1 update.  I've enabled Remote access, and checked the firewall and those items look fine.  I've also started a virtual machine (win7) on the win 8.1 box, and can RDP into that machine (which proves the networking paths are working).  The machine is on a private network, though turning off the firewall did not fix the issue, so I don't think network or firewall setting are the problem.

But trying to connect to \ on the win 8.1 host just fails with "Your credentials did not work" and "The Logon attempt failed".

This is the primary admin account I'm trying to use, so it is already an RDP "user" account.

The machine used to run windows 8 and everything worked fine.  Trying to connect from a Windows 7 client.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?  I'm stuck.

[edited for comment responses]

**Ensure you have the latest RDP client on your Win 7 machine, and ensure the client and the server are using the same authentication types.** I installed RDP updates on the win7 machine.  I'm not sure how to check the authentication types though.

**Are you trying to use saved credentials?** No

**Are you on a domain? If so, is the Windows 8.1 machine ALSO on the domain?** The win7 machine is on a domain, the win8.1 machine is not.  But same was true when I could connect to the machine when it was running Win8 (not 8.1).  I can connect to a win7 vm on the machine, which is also not on the domain.

**If not, do the credentials you're trying to use also exist on the Windows 8.1 machine?** N/A, but the account is on the win8.1 machine

**Anything in the Event logs regarding your failed logon attempts?** Which events should I be looking for, and on which machine?

[/edit]

Comment: Ensure you have the latest RDP client on your Win 7 machine, and ensure the client and the server are using the same authentication types. Are you trying to use saved credentials?  Are you on a domain? If so, is the Windows 8.1 machine ALSO on the domain?  If not, do the credentials you're trying to use also exist on the Windows 8.1 machine?  Anything in the Event logs regarding your failed logon attempts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's some sort of difference with how Windows 8.1 handles RDP authentication (I'm assuming it's something to do with certs). Either way DO NOT download the old 2.2.1 Mac client. From OS X Mavericks, just **visit the App Store and download the "Microsoft Remote Desktop"** -- current version was 8.0.5 at the time of post. This seems to be the solution; and the new client has been much improved.

The solution was discovered **[here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/2bc873ed-6c11-4767-8ce3-4df8549aff20/remote-desktop-connection-cannot-verify-the-identity-of-the-computer-that-you-want-to-connect-to?forum=winservergen)**.